# How to invoke Java methods through COM

Tags: java, com, vb6, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP/VBScript application that needs to call methods in a Java class. I discovered two products that apparently can do this: [Java2COM](http://www.nevaobject.com/_docs/_java2com/java2com.htm) and [Java COM Bridge](http://javacombridge.com/). Can you recommend one from experience, or is there yet another mechanism by which we can do this which is better? I'd rather avoid having to write C++ code if possible, although we could certainly create a COM DLL in VB6 that could in turn call low level APIs as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you basically need to have a COM Server that then uses JNI to create a JVM and make Java calls.  It is a bit tricky and examples are scarce, which may make the products you have listed helpful.  I can't vouch for either of them.

Alternatively, you may want to consider a web service based approach and get to the Java classes that way, depending on what they are and how you're using them.

Comment: Yeah a web service is the other option I'm considering. It carries some risks and I'm really trying to keep the latency down, hence my question here.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Bert. You could try [jpype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) or [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) for the jni part.
Making a com server with pywin32 in python is a cake thanks to [mark hammond](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html).
Making a com server in csharp example at [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_object_in_c_.aspx).

Comment: Interesting. I'm no longer working on this project but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) in the (distant) past, and it seemed to get the job done. The price is right, but the documentation is somewhat lacking so that's something to consider.

Comment: I've used JACOB but I'm pretty sure it does the opposite of what I want here - it allows you to create COM objects from within Java code and call methods on them. I want the opposite.